# Calculating daily mean wind speed and the mean per polygon over multiple years in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, time-series, mean

I have been trying to obtain the **daily mean wind speed per pixel per day, next, I want to calculate the mean of the new pixel values for each of the municipalities in Colombia during the period 2000-2015**. Then, after obtaining this mean I want to know how many days during the year, this mean was lower than a threshold (threshold is < 3.5 m/s).

I have only got more or less to the point of calculating the daily mean per polygon for a single year, without applying the threshold. But computation times are extremely long, which makes me believe that there is something utterly wrong with my code.

```
var fao = ee.FeatureCollection("FAO/GAUL/2015/level2");

// Filter Colombia from Worldwide dataset
var colombia = fao.filter(ee.Filter.eq('ADM0_NAME', 'Colombia'));
var counties = colombia.select('ADM1_NAME','ADM2_NAME')

var startDate = ee.Date('2020-01-01')
var endDate = ee.Date('2020-12-31')

var collection = ee.ImageCollection("NASA/GLDAS/V021/NOAH/G025/T3H")
.select('Wind_f_inst')

var numberOfDays = endDate.difference(startDate, 'days')
var daily = ee.ImageCollection(
  ee.List.sequence(0, numberOfDays.subtract(1))
    .map(function (dayOffset) {
      var start = startDate.advance(dayOffset, 'days')
      var end = start.advance(1, 'days')
      return collection
        .filterDate(start, end)
        .mean()
    })
)
Map.addLayer(daily.first().select(0), {min: 0, max: 16, palette: 'blue,green,yellow,orange,red'})

 var Wmean = daily.map(function(img) {
   return img.reduceRegions({
       collection: counties,
       reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
        scale: 5000,
     }).map(function(f){
         return f.set('date', img.date());
     });
 }).flatten();
 
 Export.table.toDrive({
   collection:Wmean,
   folder: "Google Earth Engine 2",
   description: 'wind_mean_daily',
 //  selectors:(["date","mean"]),
   });
```

Comment: 366 days x 1086 polygon it's a lot of processing time IMO. I did it at my way for getting features with ADM name, date and mean value. With a few days the process is fast enough, but doing it all at once could be slow: https://code.earthengine.google.com/b47c6194053aa9ba7a6031300e2f84de

Comment: This is exactly what I need for the first step, but as you could see the function does not print the results, I also tried exporting your results but they are not going through. I don't know if a csv file can manage this amount of information...I don't think so. For this reason, the second step is needed to reduce the number of observations in the final file. The second step consists in applying the threshold per day and see if the mean is lower than 3.5 m/s, if yes, I would sum that day to the total count. By doing so, I would reduce the number of observations down to 1086.

Comment: I don't like JS code editor for this taks TBH. I switched to python API getting tables after reductions. Take a look at this example I just uploaded: https://github.com/aldotapia/PROMMRA_Misc/blob/master/Python/evelation_gee.py . The output are CSV files

Comment: Resolution of daily mean wind speed per pixel per day is coarser than municipalities in Colombia. So, you can use another approach for doing this task in a reasonable running time. In picture (https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObUdu.png) attached in this comment, you can observe points for grid corresponding to Colombia as pixel center of first image of your collection. I programmed my script for three points observed in image (red rectangle). In Tab Console, it was printed counts (days with threshold < 3.5 m/s ) for years 2001, 2002 and 2003 (not leap years) for points 10, 11 and 12.

Comment: After finishing my script, I test it for complete dates range (2000-2015; 16 years) and 20 points; inside red polygon of attached picture (https://i.stack.imgur.com/3G9vR.png). It spent one hour (my Internet is not good) for running it in GEE code editor. In that image, it can also be observed counts (days with threshold < 3.5 m/s) for these 20 points, between 2000-2015 years, for obtained CSV. There were processed 116880 values (5844 values per year x 20 points).